# Disable matplotlib's default arrow key bindings

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using matplotlib's `mpl_connect` functionality, one can bind events to function calls. However, the left and right arrow key are by default bound to go "back" and "forward" in the figure's history. I would like to disable this default binding.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def on_key_press(event):
    if event.key == "left":
        print("Left!")
    elif event.key == "right":
        print("Right!")

plt.plot([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 2, 1, 2, 5])
plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", on_key_press)
```

Pressing the left key will now print `Left!` to the console. However, when we zoom into the figure, then the left key will also go "back", and zoom back out. (The right key will go "forward" and zoom back in.) I would like this to not happen - how do I do that? Making `on_key_press` return `False` doesn't do the trick.

(Background info: I have bindings set up so that, when the user clicks on the figure, a cursor will appear, centered on the plotted point (as given by [0,1,2,3,4] and [5,2,1,2,5]) that is closest to where the user clicked. I can make the left and right keys move this cursor to the previous/next data point, but if the user happens to be zoomed in, or has done any other manipulation to the graph, things go bad.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To remove *all* of the default key bindings

```
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(fig.canvas.manager.key_press_handler_id)
```

however this is using a sledge hammer when you need a scalpel.  Looking at the [handler function](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v1.5.1/lib/matplotlib/backend_bases.py#L2462) the default key bindings are pulled from the rcparams so

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['keymap.back'].remove('left')
mpl.rcParams['keymap.forward'].remove('right')
```

will disable just the `'left'` and `'right'` keys.

Those `remove` calls should probably be wrapped in `try...except` as they will raise if the value is not in the list (ex, your users already re-mapped them).  It might be worth looping over all of the rcparams used by the handler to make sure *none* of them conflict.

Comment: Still somewhat of a sledgehammer, as this disables it for every axes in figure, but it's good enough for me. Thanks!

Comment: The other option is to remove the callback on a per axes basis and replace it will a vendored modified version of the default key handler.

Comment: It would be nice to have a way to only change it locally (for a specific axis)

Answer (score 3):

In order to find the other Key maps......

```
  import matplotlib as mpl 
    for k,v in mpl.rcParams.items():
      if -1 != k.find("keymap"):
        print "rcParams[%s]=%s"%(k,v)
```