# Pyplot warning when evaluating expression from textbox widget

Tags: python, matplotlib, warnings, axes

If I have a pyplot figure with more than one "axes" (as they call them) and there is a textbox in one of them, when writing some special sequences of characters (e.g. `*2`) I get a warning that states the following:

```sh
MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Toggling axes navigation from the keyboard is deprecated since 3.3 and will be removed two minor releases later.
  return self.func(*args)
```

Note that this doesn't seem to happen if I only have one single axes.

I'd need to use such a textbox to intert a function that will be evaluated, so I need to work with `*` and `**` perhaps. What is causing this warning?

Here's a minimal example to recreate the scenario:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import TextBox

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
tb1 = TextBox(ax1, 'Textbox: ')
ax2.plot([1,2,3,4,5])
plt.show()
```

Comment: This also happens when you press 1 or 2 while hovering one of the charts, even without the TextBox.

Comment: Wouldn't have noticed on my own. Why does this happen? Are these perhaps some keyboard shortcuts? If so, how to un-bind them?

Comment: Couldn't find a good way to disable it yet, but a quickfix can be `import warnings; warnings.simplefilter("ignore", matplotlib.MatplotlibDeprecationWarning)` to disable this warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can unbind default key bindings in matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import TextBox

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(fig.canvas.manager.key_press_handler_id)
tb1 = TextBox(ax1, 'Textbox: ')
ax2.plot([1,2,3,4,5])
plt.show()
```

[More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35631062/8627992) - you can apparently also specify which binding to ignore.

Another way would be to just suppress this warning:

```
import warnings
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import TextBox

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore", matplotlib.MatplotlibDeprecationWarning)
    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
    tb1 = TextBox(ax1, 'Textbox: ')
    ax2.plot([1,2,3,4,5])
    plt.show()
```